# Вывести значения за пределы карты

Tags: javascript, html, dom, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как в этом примере вывести данные по доставке за пределы карты в 
 `<div id="result"></div>` ?

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="m-4">
        <p>Для рачёта доставки выберите место на карте</p>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете задать контент div-блока в той же части кода, где заполняете данными балун.

```
if (activeRoute) {   

...

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Итого:<br/> <span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
'<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>';

}
```

Comment: Например, вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/4umu1L3q/